# Bind Solaris 10 swap file

Tags: database, solaris, swap

I have created an Oracle swap file to enhance my swap space. I have to do this for a Oracle Client installation.

After creating swap file I Run the swap command to specify the additional swap space by typing:

`swap -a /directory/swap-file-name`

Then I verify that the extra swap space was added by typing: `swap -s`

Now my Problem:

At a restart Solaris 10 the additional swap space is missing and must bind again. Is there any Option for an automatically bind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add this into the vfstab so you would add a line like this

`/path/to/file  -   -  swap   -   no   -`